# MATLAB equivalent of Mathematica's Sum

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to find the simplest MATLAB equivalent command of this Mathematica code

```
Sum[i^2,{i,1,10}]
```

Comment: i=1:10; sum(i.^2); 
Is this what you need? Let me know so I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you correctly then:

```
x = sum((1:10).^2);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Is there a way so we don't have to construct unnecessary array x?

Comment: Thanks, how about Sum[i/(i+1)^2,{i,1,10}]?

Comment: sum((1:10)./(2:11).^2)

Answer (score 0):

You will first declare `i` as a vector containing the values over which you will sum.

```
i=1:10;
```

Then you simply sum the vector of the squares:

```
sum(i.^2)

ans =  385
```